# How to dedupelicate a List<SObject> if not with a map?

Tags: apex, map, list, set

I'm confused that something doesn't work, which I thought to be the best practise for removing duplicate SObjects from a `List<SObject>`.

```
Account a = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];   
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(new List<Account>{a,a});
```

throws

> System.ListException: Row with duplicate Id at index

1. **How else should I do this in a one liner instead of looping over it?**
2. **AND why from a conceptual standpoint does the map-way not work??**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use the `.putAll()` method to convert a list of sObjects to a map with the record Id as the key.

```
Account a = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];   
List<Account> lsAccounts = new List<Account>{a,a};
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
accounts.putAll(lsAccounts);
System.debug('Map:' + accounts);
```

The above gives the following output:

> DEBUG|Map:{001i000000cyPNCAA2=Account:{Name=GenePoint,
>   Id=001i000000cyPNCAA2}}

Answer (score 4):

Found this on [salesforce developer forums](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008y3SIAQ).
Sets are by definition unique so this should work.

```
Set<Account> myset = new Set<sobject>();
List<Account> originalList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
List<Account> result = new List<Account>();
myset.addAll(result);
result.addAll(myset);
```

Comment: I also used that as a solution. But I would also like to learn why the map way doesn't work. I believe I have seen that as a solution before.

Answer (score 2):

Map won't work this way because Maps are a collection of key-value pair and key is always unique here. So Map won't work if ids are duplicate.